# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, word-count

I am trying to create an algorithm for word count in JavaScript, I am creating a for-in loop to fetch each word from array and then pushing them to the object but getting error while I am setting each object key to each array value.

```js
const wordCount = input => {
  let newArr = input.split(" ");
  let obj = {};
  for (let i in newArr) {
    console.log(newArr[i]); // This returns value
    obj.newArr[i] = 1;  // This gives error:- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
  }
  console.log(obj);
};
wordCount("heyy how you doin heyy");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const wordCount = input => {
  let newArr = input.split(" ");
  let obj = {};
  for (let i in newArr) {
   // console.log(newArr[i]); // This returns value
    obj[newArr[i]] = 1;  // This gives error:- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
   
  }
  console.log(obj);
};
wordCount("heyy how you doin heyy");
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't add those brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initalize `newArr` as a field in `obj`:

```js
const wordCount = input => {
  let newArr = input.split(" ");
  let obj = { newArr: [] };
  for (let i in newArr) {
    console.log(newArr[i]); // This returns value
    obj.newArr[i] = 1;  // This gives error:- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
  }
  console.log(obj);
};
wordCount("heyy how you doin heyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no property `newArray` in your `obj` object.

```js
const wordCount = input => {
  let newArr = input.split(" ");
  let obj = {newArr: []};
  for (let i in newArr) {
    console.log(newArr[i]); // This returns value
    obj.newArr[i] = 1;  // This gives error:- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
  }
  console.log(obj);
};
wordCount("heyy how you doin heyy");
```